# is there a better algorithm to this problem?

Tags: algorithm, search, time-complexity, binary-search-tree, binary-search

I have the below problem:

Mary intends to purchase a cupboard of volume at least X mm^3. For every positive whole number n, there exists a unique cupboard that Mary can buy for ‘n’ pounds, and the unique cupboard would have the measurements: depth (5*n + 5) mm, width (5*n) mm and height (2^n) mm.

I need to come up with an algorithm that runs in Olog((logX)) worst case time that calculates the least amount Mary has to pay to purchase an appropriate cupboard.

I can only think of an O(logX) solution with binary search. Help would be much appreciated.

my solution below in python:

```
import math
# scanning the input for X
X = input("Enter a value:\n")
left = 0
right = math.log(int(X),2)
final = 0
while (left <= right):
    middle = (left + right) // 2;
    temp_vol = 5 * middle * (5 * middle + 5) * (2**middle);
    if (temp_vol >= int(X)):
        final = middle;
        right = middle - 1;
    else :
        left = middle + 1;
            
print(f'the min pay out is: {final}')
```

Comment: Perhaps authous mean [interpolation search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm#Interpolation_search). Also consider searching in logarithmic space - linear interpolation will work nice there.

Comment: @MBo could you please explain further on how that would be used in this particular problem?

Comment: Explain what? Interpolation search?

Comment: @MBo yes, used in this example

Comment: Cannot just now. But I noticed you don't need it. Look at answer

Comment: Try treating this as a calculus problem rather than a programming problem.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. how would calculus come into play in this problem?

Comment: You are essentially required to find a root of a monotonically increasing differentiable function, then round it up to an integer.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. and how would that take Olog((logX)) worst case time?

Comment: I note than n=277 already gives you a cupboard larger than the observable universe at 4e80 m³ :D

Answer (score 2):

If you perform linear search by `n` value (just simple `n` incrementing loop), then volume rises exponentially, so you reach volume `X` in `log(X)` steps

When you perform binary search by `n` value, you make `log(log(X))` steps, so your solution is already fine.

Comment: This is only true if you choose your initial search interval correctly. If it's say n times bigger than it needs to be, there are additional log(n) steps to make. How do you choose the interval?

Comment: @n. 1.8e9-where's-my-share m.  Author's evaluation as log(X) is good enough to provide error about log(log(X)). It is possible to use exponential search (step doubling, then halving), but I think it is not needed here.